# Share global state between multiple NodeJS Instances

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having this dilemma that has been in my head for quite sometime.
My plan is to have three separate NodeJS instances each running it's core task.

So in case that any one of the instances crashes, the rest remains active and operational whilst considering the downtime of that NodeJS instance.

The real problem I am currently having is how I am able to persist static variables (it can be classed based variables as well, e.g. Discord Client, Database Client, etc...) through these instances.

My solution was to use the global variable, but I'm sure that the global variable doesn't persist between these NodeJS instances.

Is there any other solution you guys have in mind that allows me to share these class based variables for each NodeJS instance to use (like a local database)? Thank you

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I had two plans, both has been tested but failed what I wanted to achieve.

First plan was to utilize the global variable, but it doesn't persist between each NodeJS instance.

Second plan was to combine all of the project to one, each having it's own catch to restart itself. This allows it to use the global variable within the same instance, but sadly it doesn't achieve the downtime catch (and it is quite frustrating to navigate such a large codebase). Another problem with this is that if I want to restart one section of the project, it restarts all of them.

Comment: Please include what you already have tried in the question

Comment: @PascalLamers, apologies... I pressed Enter without pressing Shift. The message has been udpated

Comment: Not clear in your question, whether you want to run multiple instances of same service or run multiple services.
- If you want to run multiple instances of same server then pm2 npm automatically manages clustering and helps you to run multi instance of same service
- If you want to run multiple services at once, then pm2 also helps you to auto restart service if goes down

Comment: The question is to run multiple services at once, whilst having a solution to persist global variables with each other.